# Change pie chart color in Kibana

Tags: pie-chart, kibana

One of my uses of Kibana is related to displaying some information in certain cases only (say when a value is unexpected and exceeds a defined range). This element is therefore either shown or hidden from the dashboard, and displaying it could be considered as displaying an alert. I would prefer if the related pie chart was filled in red, rather than the default green.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are describing Kibana 3, if you want terms panels pie charts to use different colors, you will need to make a code change.

There is a way to have custom colors for your pie chart. In order to do that you'll need to create a "hits" panel and pick the "pie chart" as the display. The color of the pie slices will be determined by the color that you chose for the queries that they track:

[image]